# Issue adding more changesets to liquibase changelog file

Tags: sql, sql-server, liquibase

After my most recent change in Liquibase I cannot get anything else to be added without causing a checksum error. I'm not very used to working with Liquibase so please forgive my ignorance.

Here is my last changeset:

```
-- changeset Conner:492 splitStatements="false" endDelimiter=";" :/

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateOrInsertWinningColorsAnswers(@json NVARCHAR(max)) AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON  
    MERGE INTO WinningColorsAnswer W
    USING(
            SELECT *
            FROM OPENJSON(@json)
            WITH(
                Id int,
                Answer varchar(max),
                QuestionId int,
                SectionId int,
                StudentChallengeMappingId int,
                CreatedDate datetime2,
                CreatedUser varchar(20),
                UpdatedDate datetime2,
                UpdatedUser varchar(20),
                IsDeleted bit        
            )
        ) as InputJSON (Id,
                Answer,
                QuestionId,
                SectionId,
                StudentChallengeMappingId,
                CreatedDate,
                CreatedUser,
                UpdatedDate,
                UpdatedUser,
                IsDeleted)
    ON(W.StudentChallengeMappingId = InputJSON.StudentChallengeMappingId and W.QuestionId = InputJSON.QuestionId)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
        SET W.Answer = InputJSON.Answer,
            W.UpdatedDate = Convert(datetime, InputJSON.UpdatedDate, 104),
            W.UpdatedUser = InputJSON.UpdatedUser
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT(Answer,QuestionId,SectionId,StudentChallengeMappingId,CreatedDate,CreatedUser,UpdatedDate,UpdatedUser,IsDeleted)
        VALUES(InputJSON.Answer,
        InputJSON.QuestionId,
        InputJSON.SectionId,
        InputJSON.StudentChallengeMappingId,
        Convert(datetime, InputJSON.CreatedDate, 104),
        InputJSON.CreatedUser,
        Convert(datetime, InputJSON.UpdatedDate, 104),
        InputJSON.UpdatedUser,
        Cast(InputJSON.IsDeleted as bit))
    ;
END
/
```

When I go to add the next changeset like this:

```
-- changeset Conner:493

-- code down here
--
--
--
--
--
```

I get the following error message.

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: Validation Failed:
> 1 change sets check sum
> changelog.mssql.sql::492::Conner was: 8:0bde397236550cd1a364241c50171677 but is now: 8:cd9ef9c9a83fda6b8bd33543b4322bef

I didn't make any changes to `-- changeset Conner:492` so what is causing the change that makes the checksum become invalid?

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to a similar post on the Liquibase Forum. Here's the suggested solution there:

> 1. run a `clear-checksums` command followed by an `update` command. This will clear all `md5sums` and recalculate them during the update,
>    which will prevent the error.
> 2. Add `--validCheckSum` to your changeset with the new value. (see: [Example Changelogs: SQL Format | Liquibase Docs](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/sql-format.html?Highlight=validchecksum&_ga=2.245380484.1472105324.1663606258-1117896858.1647989253))
> 3. Update the `databasechangelog` table, setting the `md5sum` to `NULL` for the particular row. This will do basically the same as #1.

Reference:

1. https://forum.liquibase.org/t/how-to-fix-validationfailedexception-in-liquibase-checksum/6780/6